# MySQL query does not return all available rows in a simple query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which searches a table for product sizes where purchased is greater then sold and groups it by size so i can index all available sizes in cart.

However, it does not return all available sizes.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stock_live 
WHERE `purchased` > `sold` AND (`stock`='1' AND product_id='13') 
GROUP BY size 
ORDER BY size ASC
```

Available sizes in the stock_live table there are 3 sizes available, but it only returns two and escapes one.

Here is the MySQL table with the results returned:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock_live` (
  `ID` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `waqt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stock` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `size` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `purchased` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `sold` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `purchase_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lot_no` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `file_no` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `Tfrom` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Transferred From',
  `Tto` tinytext COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Transferred TO',
  `old_pid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Old purchase_id',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1054 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `stock_live`
--

INSERT INTO `stock_live` (`ID`, `waqt`, `stock`, `product_id`, `size`, `purchased`, `sold`, `purchase_id`, `lot_no`, `file_no`, `Tfrom`, `Tto`, `old_pid`) VALUES
(942, 1445451326, 1, 13, '0.7ML', '14400.00', '0.00', 0, '2200', 'G-54', '930', '', 0),
(21, 1445451326, 1, 13, '250ML', '360.00', '116.00', 43, '240', 'F-82', '0', '|277|330|712', 0);
```

And it escapes this row:

```
INSERT INTO `stock_live` (`ID`, `waqt`, `stock`, `product_id`, `size`, `purchased`, `sold`, `purchase_id`, `lot_no`, `file_no`, `Tfrom`, `Tto`, `old_pid`) VALUES
(295, 1445451326, 1, 13, '150ML', '114', '36', 62, '5011', 'Z-400', '0', '|306|331', 0);
```

Comment: side note, you don't need quotes around integers in MySQL. Using quotes when not needed can create an unnecessary security risk.

Comment: Can you show what it gets and what the desired output is.

Comment: Show the output of `SELECT * FROM stock_live WHERE product_id = 13`

Comment: And show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE stock_live` also, please

Comment: My guess is that there are only two sizes where `purchased` > `sold`.  If you want to show all sizes anyway, you'll have to use a derived table.

Comment: Thank you all for your time, please have a look at the question i have updated it with mysql table and insert data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit, it seems the problem is in your table schema.

You defined `purchased` and `sold` as VARCHAR fields. It's doing string comparison, and "114" < "36" in string comparison, just as "Apple" < "Blackberry".

Redefine your table with INT columns so it compares their numeric values:

```
 ALTER TABLE `stock_live` 
    CHANGE COLUMN `purchased` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    CHANGE COLUMN `sold` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: there are more than 30 sizes and they are random

Comment: Added another example that will show all sizes in your table.

Comment: codedudey, do you have a second table that has your sizes enumerated?

Comment: I have another table where sizes are selected as an array, but that is irrelevant to this scenario if you create the table with above data i sent, you will see there are 4 rows and one is escaped i think mysql fails to do the purchased > sold on one.
there is another database Old one which the query works just fine with it but not this one.

Comment: @codedudey - No - the first query in my answer will return a row for each `size` in the `stock_live` table.  Your problem is likely missing data in the table.  Your other database probably has more data, with at least one record for each size.  Again, if you want to make this work without records in stock_live for each size, you either need to join on another table or a derived table, per my answer.

Comment: If you have a table with all sizes, you could use my last example, and replace the `FROM` clause with `FROM size_list LEFT JOIN stock_live ON ...`

Comment: check the mysql table with two insert data, there is one entry for size 150ML purchased 114.00 sold 36.00 and its not being showed.

Comment: That's because `purchased` and `sold` are varchar fields.  It's doing string comparison, and "116" < "36" in string comparison

Comment: @codedudey - Changed my answer - seems it's a schema issue.

Comment: @codedudey - Why `DECIMAL`?  Do you have fractional purchased / sold values?

Comment: FYI, `DECIMAL(10,0)` is essentially a poorly-performing `INT`.  Why'd you suggest that edit?

Comment: all the items are sold based on cartons and dozens like 1.2 or 1.33 i am trying to convert a 2004 system to a new system, i am doing my best to do things the right way :) thank you for your efforts and this answer is correct.

Comment: @codedudey - if you can have two decimal places, you need to change your decimal to `DECIMAL(10,2)`.  `(10,0)` will round the result to 0 decimal places.